# 我也住在這裡 or 我也住這裡

Tags: sentence-structure

I'm quite confused with using 在 in a sentence. I learned that it usually indicates a  place or a location. I'm trying to say "I also live here". I thought that since I'm referring to a place, maybe I will need to use 在. But when I remove it, the sentence sounds correct as well. Which sentence would be more appropriate?

Comment: Welcome to Chinese SE Daphne!

Comment: But in speaking Chinese, we like to remove anything that don't necessarily have to be there. I prefer `我也住這裡` personally.

Comment: In northern China, people would say "我也住这儿"

Comment: 我也住在这里 or 我也住这里 Both correct.

Comment: i think they are same meaning!

Comment: There is an article (in Chinese) illustrates well how prepositions are omitted sometimes: [汉语口语中的介词省略](http://wuxizazhi.cnki.net/Search/AFJY199701015.html)

Answer (score 10):

Grammatically 在 is required.

Unlike in English 'here' is an adverb which can follow verb directly, in Chinese 这里 is a pronoun, in order to construct a V-O phrase, there must be a preposition in between.

In colloquial language, people often omit 在, so it's also understood and appropriate, just less formal.

Answer (score 0):

Actually both sentences means the same, but when you try to breakdown each word meaning, it should be like:

- 我 - 也 - 住 - **在** - 這裡: I - also - live - **in** - here.
- 我 - 也 - 住 - 這裡: I - also - live - here.

The last sentence lack of preposition but it still able to understood and looks like less formal.

Btw, the sentence should be constructed like S  O  V, and it should be like: 我也在這裡住, isn't it? But when the order like this, I think you can't omit 在.

Answer (score -4):

When you study and speak Chinese, remember one thing: There is no such thing as grammar in Chinese. If you want to speak Chinese fluently, forget all about grammar.

So in this problem, "我也住在这里"="我也住这里". They are identical! Which one you like, you use which one. No Chinese will blame you for using one but not another. (I am a Chinese, believe me)

Comment: no such thing as grammar in chinese? false and unhelpful.

Comment: You speak as if you know Chinese more than a Chinese.

Comment: Maybe you're confused about what "grammar" means. Chinese lacks conjugation, declension, and agreement, but to say there is "no such thing as grammar in Chinese" is patently false.

Comment: @ZhouHeng 你语文没学好吧。